# Deleting from SP is not working properly- Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

below is my SP:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DELETE_Sample(
                 sample_key Number)IS
Begin
delete from sample where sample_key=sample_key;
End;
```

On Executing this am expecting a particular row get deleted which has the matching sample_key.

```
begin
  -- Call the procedure
  DELETE_Sample(sample_key => 12);

end;
```

But what is happening is every data in the sample table get deleted, meaning "where" class is not getting applied. and it is taking like "Delete from sample" and delete all the records.

This is to weird . Is this even possible? Can anyone help me on this.

PS: this is my first work with Oracle.  its really tough to figure out whats wrong here.

Comment: Only issue is that the stored procedure has a parameter with specified length i.e. just convert `Number(10)` to `Number` ( [Refer](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c1049b7d925083b8af7f2364f51a7058) )

Comment: Your procedure must be throwing errors while compiling.

Comment: is it possible that your column is also named `ag_key` (the same name as the parameter)?

Comment: Yes the issue is column name and parameter name are same.after changing that its working good. thanks for the time @a_horse_with_no_name,@Tejash,@Barbaros Ozhan